# Select gender in android like radioButton

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I'm making a simple program where I want to be able to select my gender much like a radio-button behaviour, you either check female or male, and the other choice is supposed to be unchecked. I have separate images for the buttons, both pressed and not pressed.

I've stored the states in a selector file:

**button_female.xml** :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gender_f"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gender_f" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gender_f_notpressed" />
</selector>
```

And in **layout/settings_activity.xml** :

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/maleButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_male"
        android:onClick="onGenderButtonClicked"
        />
```

And in the activity, the onClick is written as

```
   public void onGenderButtonClicked(View view) {
        if(feButton.isPressed()){
            maButton.setEnabled(false);
            radioPressed = true;
        } else if (maButton.isPressed()){
            feButton.setEnabled(false);
            radioPressed = true;
        } else {
            radioPressed = false;
        }

    }
```

However, this doesn't work for several reasons..

**1** : The pictures on the buttons don't show up, either pressed or unpressed.

**2** : My code is *bad*, the buttons don't work as expected. I would like to have them behave as a radio group (you either choose male or female as your gender)..

So I seem to have two problems here. Does anyone know a good way to solve this? I'm very new to writing android apps..

Comment: do check these two examples for the same case: [one](http://arjun30.blogspot.in/2013/05/radio-button-example-android.html)  
, [two](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/)

Comment: you can go for segmented button as well https://github.com/vinc3m1/android-segmentedradiobutton

Comment: @user2450263 Thank you, but the examples you referred to don't mention using image buttons. I've messed around with radio buttons that work, but I want some buttons i've designed on my own to work like radio buttons do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need something like this:

[image]

You can use this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGrp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/gender_old"
            android:paddingTop="64dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            >
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioM"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:checked="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/male"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:text="Male"
            />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioF"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:checked="false"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/female"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:text="Female"
            />
        </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have here a great example for what you need:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

The layout:

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioSex"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioMale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_male" 
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_female" />

</RadioGroup>
```

And for controling:

```
private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
private RadioButton radioSexButton;
private Button btnDisplay;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {
radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// get selected radio button from radioGroup
int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
// find the radiobutton by returned id
radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use a radioGroup in xml as below :

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_female"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_female"
            android:text="female" />
    </RadioGroup>
```